# How to find the base, given a number and its representation in the base?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

If 211 in base $x$ is 152 base 8, how to find $x$? With trial and error or there's a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base $8$, the number $152$ represents $1\cdot8^2 + 5\cdot8 + 2 = 64+40+2=106$. Similarly, in base $x$, $211$ represents $2x^2 + 1x + 1$. Now solve $2x^2+x+1 = 106$.

Comment: Isn't there any other method. Because this method is not always possible. What if in base $x$, the number is 111?

Comment: What if the equation has no real roots?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal $111_x = x^2+x+1$. If the equation has no real roots, then clearly there is no solution.

Answer (score 3):

Others have indicated a method which will work in the general case. However the base is clearly greater than $2$, because it uses a digit $2$, and less than $8$, because it needs a $2$ in the hundreds place, and base $8$ only has a $1$. So the only bases to try are $3,4,5,6,7$.

There are other observations which would suggest trying high numbers first. For example, $5^2=25$ and you need three of these to make $75=113_8$.

And you might also observe that $152_8$ is even, while $211$ is only even in an odd base.

So trial can be made pretty efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$211_{x}=2\cdot x^2+1\cdot x+1=2x^2+x+1$$
$$152_{8}=1\cdot8^2+5\cdot8+2=106$$

Then solve for $x$.